# Dremio connection in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, dremio

I'm new to Dremio. Could anyone help me with how to build dremio connection in snowflake.

> CREATE STAGE <stage_name>
> URL = 'http://<dremio_host>:9047'
> CREDENTIALS = (USERNAME='' PASSWORD='')
> DATA_FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
> FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = 'PARQUET')
> I have seen this, but not sure about the exact syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what you mean by a “Dremio connection in Snowflake” but if you mean make Snowflake a source for Dremio then this is documented [here](https://docs.dremio.com/software/data-sources/snowflake/).

If this is not what you mean, can you explain what you are trying to achieve?